# MYSQL : return what matched with multiple search criteria

Tags: mysql

This is my table-structure.

[image]

I have a query like ,

```
SELECT `user_pid` from `table` WHERE 
`upchain` LIKE '%,33,%' OR `upchain` LIKE '%,52,%' OR upchain LIKE '%,98,%'
```

which gives result like :

[image]

But I need to know which row matched which search criteria.
Is there any way to get following result :

```
user_pid | search_critetis
--------------------------
  33     |    ,33,
  52     |    ,52,
  98     |    ,98,
  100    |    ,98,
  101    |    ,98,
```

Comment: You should really change your table design. Never store multiple values in a single column

Comment: @juergend : Yeah, I know. I had to create this table for one particular task.This is not my main table.

Comment: @kadamb Could we solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If possible you can rewrite the query as

```
SELECT `user_pid` ,'%,33,%' from `table` WHERE 
`upchain` LIKE '%,33,%' 
 union all
SELECT `user_pid` ,'%,52,%' from `table` WHERE 
 `upchain` LIKE '%,52,%'
```

You can also rewrite the query using `case`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT user_pid, 
       CASE WHEN upchain LIKE '%,33,%' THEN ',33,' ELSE
       CASE WHEN upchain LIKE '%,52,%' THEN ',52,' ELSE
       CASE WHEN upchain LIKE '%,98,%' THEN ',98,' END END END as upchain
FROM table
WHERE upchain LIKE '%,33,%' OR upchain LIKE '%,52,%' OR upchain LIKE '%,98,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
user_pid,
IF( upchain LIKE '%,33,%', '%,33,% condition' , 
    IF(
        upchain like '%,52,%', '%,52,% condition', 
        IF(
            upchain like '%,98,%', '%,98,% condition', 
            'other condition'
        )               
    ) 
) 
as condition from table
```

You can use this syntax and add multiple condition as you like.

```
IF('your condition', << true part >>, "another condition OR elase part")
```